# Echo but retain all quotes

Tags: macos, function, shell, zsh

Is it possible to echo a text and keep all quotes and double quotes in place?
I want to write a function to copy the text currently written in the terminal (completely with quotes).

Since I am on OSX I have to use pbcopy:

`pb(){echo "$@" | pbcopy}`

But `pb osascript -e 'tell Application "iTerm" to display dialog "Job finished"'` does return

`osascript -e tell Application "iTerm" to display dialog "Job finished"` but not

`osascript -e tell 'Application "iTerm" to display dialog "Job finished"'`.

Comment: At its core this is a shell escaping question.  Escaping data at the shell is a pain, doubly so if it has both single and double quotes; that's why I wouldn't make use of such a shell function. Instead, to write small strings to pbpaste I would use `pbcopy<<<"stdin to \`pbcopy\` is \"this\""`.  For longer bits of text I'd use a multiline heredoc `pbcopy<<-'__eof__'`.   The few extra characters are well worth the clarity, and it needs no function initialization so is more "vanilla" too.

Comment: Hey thanks for jumping in! I do not really know how to use the here strings. (I can see how heredocs are used in the answer below). Simply `pbcopy<<<"stdin to `pbcopy` is \"this\""` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to echo a text and keep all quotes and double quotes in place? I want to write a function to copy the text currently written in the terminal (completely with quotes).

Let's explore what you mean by "currently written in the terminal".  If I understand correctly, you want to provide arbitrary input to a shell command at invocation time.  In other words, you have a bit of text that you want to add into your copy buffer, and you want to send it to the stdin of `pbcopy` to do so.

As a solution to this particular problem, a shell function is a poor fit.  That's because a shell function needs to be invoked with arguments that are subject to shell interpretation, and so you'll have to escape them carefully both when invoking `pb` and when defining it.  These strings can be escaped.  But it's inconvenient, for one thing because there are several special characters that need to be escaped in a double quoted string, but `'` can't itself be escaped in a single quoted string.

Let's explore some other options.

```
$ pbcopy <<< "this is a simple one-line string directly from the command line.  Since it's an argument to pbcopy it needs to be escaped."
$ pbpaste
this is a simple one-line string directly from the command line.  Since it's an argument to pbcopy it needs to be escaped.
```

Here we tell the shell to provide the text to `pbpaste`'s standard input.  We still have to escape the string.  But we don't have to pass it anywhere or correctly enquote it again to make it a valid shell argument.

Or we can provide multi-line string data to `pbcopy` without having to enquote it with this special here-doc syntax:

```
$ pbcopy <<-'-my-chosen-delimiter'
> Since this string's delimiter is single quoted,
> no interpolation will occur.  That means " double quotes
> have no meaning, nor does ' single quotes, $dollar signs
> or other such meaningful bash syntaxes.
> -my-chosen-delimiter

$ pbpaste
Since this string's delimiter is single quoted,
no interpolation will occur.  That means " double quotes
have no meaning, nor does ' single quotes, $dollar signs
or other such meaningful bash syntaxes.
```

> I have thought that bash would be more powerful than that.

Well, on one hand, I think this is a very good opportunity to compare and contrast command line arguments (which are inherently positional by design and thus must be parsed and split by, usually, whitespace between arguments) to input and output streams expressed with `|` pipelines.  I/O streams are designed to hold arbitrary data; it's not bash's fault that you wanted to make one into a shell-parsed variable list.  It's not the considerable power of bash you're observing here, it's the functional limit of your bash knowledge.

But on the other hand, you're kind of right.  The concessions to the user-interactive command line interface, substantial historical constraints to achieve backwards compatibility, and many valid design considerations made `bash` what it is.  I for one find it and its ilk to  be by far the most powerful user interface to a computer.  But I wouldn't use it to assemble a complex application because, frankly, it's syntactically difficult.  So don't expect bash to be something it's not.  If you don't want to understand it's quirky and esoteric irregularities, stick with something more recent and more pedantic like python , go , ruby, node, or whatever non unix centric people run these days:P

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate post and thanks for showing me off the limits of bash. Finally, I found a solution for my personal script I will present it in a new answer. It really helped me to view the command as a conjunction of arguments than as pure text.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post answers for some reason... SO banned me lol. So I post my answer here. And I will add it when I am allowed later..

Comment: ``` #!/bin/sh for var in "$@" do if [ $(wc -w <<< $var) \> 1 ] then all="${all} '${var}'" else all="${all} ${var}" fi; done echo $all | pbcopy ``` This script solves my problem. It iterates over all arguments of the script "$@" and then I simply count the amount of words of each argument. If the amount of words is below 2 there is no need for additional quotes, otherwise quotes are added around the argument (those were lost while reading the arguments with multiple words).

Comment: POSIX `[` doesn't define a `>` operator; there's no guarantee that will work. If you have a specific shell in mind that *does* define a `>` operator, then use that shell, not `/bin/sh`. You likely want `-gt`, though, since you want a numerical comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The shell is removing the outer single quotes before `pb` ever sees the argument(s). Pass a *single* argument

```
pb "osascript -e 'tell Application \"iTerm\" to display dialog \"Job finished\"'"
```

to `pb`, and define it as

```
pb () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" | pbcopy
}
```

It would probably be just as easy to use a here document, though, rather than define a function that feeds its argument to `pbcopy`:

```
$ pbcopy <<'EOF'
osascript -e 'tell Application "iTerm" to display dialog "Job finished"'
EOF
```

Slightly more typing, but no need to nest so many quotes.

Comment: Works.  Just be ready to enquote and escape the input to `pb`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have really hoped that there is a better way without escaping the quotes. Is there really now other option? I have thought that bash would be more powerful than that.

Comment: @Tillus You have to realize that a command like `pb osascript -e 'tell Application ...'` is written in the shell language, and its *meaning in that language* is to run the `pb` command, with the arguments "`osascript`", "`-e`", and "`tell Application ...`". The single-quotes around the last argument are *not* part of the argument, they just remove the normal special effects of characters within them (e.g. spaces as argument delimiters). That *is their meaning in shell syntax*. What you are asking for is for your `pb` command to *not conform to shell syntax*.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this comment helped me in finding a solution (described in the other answers comments for now)